# is this a simple monad example?

Tags: clojure, monads

This is my attempt to grok monadic functions after watching [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Brian-Beckman-Dont-fear-the-Monads).

`h` uses `bind` to compose together two arbitrary functions `f` and `g`. What is the `unit` operator in this case?

```
;; f :: int -> [str]
;; g :: str -> [keyword]
;; bind :: [str] -> (str -> [keyword]) -> [keyword]
;; h :: int -> [keyword]

(defn f [v]
  (map str (range v)))

(defn g [s]
  (map keyword (repeat 4 s)))

(defn bind [l f]
  (flatten
   (map f l)))

(f 8)   ;; :: (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
(g "s") ;; :: (:s :s :s :s)

(defn h [v]
  (bind (f v) g))

(h 9) 
;; :: (:0 :0 :0 :0 :1 :1 :1 :1 :2 :2 :2 :2 :3 :3 :3 :3 :4 :4 :4 :4 :5 :5 :5 :5)
```

---

Ah, thanks for the comments; I see where I was confused.

I was familiar with these functions and how to compose them using bind:

```
f0 :: a -> M a
g0 :: a -> M a
```

but not with these functions:

```
f1 :: a -> M b
g1 :: b -> M c
```

but essentially, the `bind` operator is the same for both cases if `M` is the same. In my case, `M` is the list monad so `f1` and `g1` can be combined the same way as `f0` and `g0`.

Comment: I've changed the type comments a bit; are they still okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to implement the list monad?  If so, then it would be:

```
(defn unit [x]
  [x])
```

This is based on the [Haskell implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#return):

```
instance  Monad []  where
    m >>= k             = foldr ((++) . k) [] m
    return x            = [x]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a list monad, and so the `unit` operator is *x* ↦ [*x*], i.e.

```
(defn return [x] [x])
```

(Called `return` after the Haskell function of the same name & purpose.)

One can see that this is the unit operator by checking it satisfies [the monad laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monads_in_functional_programming#Axioms):

```
(bind (return a) f) => (bind [a] f) 
      => (flatten (map f [a])) => (flatten [f a]) => f a  ;; f returns a vector
```

And similarly for `(bind x return)`.